# Can't send query to db

Tags: php, mysqli

im trying out some code by my own. I just started to learn PHP & mysql. Could anyone tell me where is the mistake? I got a error when processing the query.
My db is set like in the code.
Db name: sweepstakes
Table name: alfa

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "";
    $dbname = "sweepstakes";

 $db = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass, $dbname);

 if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
      die("Database connection failed: " .
          mysqli_connect_errno() .
          " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
      );
    }


     if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'
        && $_POST['submit']=='Submit'
        && !empty($_POST['name'])
        && !empty($_POST['description'])
        && !empty($_POST['adress'])) {

            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $desc = $_POST['description'];
            $adress = $_POST['adress'];

                $query = "INSERT INTO alfa (name, description, adress) VALUES ('$name', '$desc', '$adress')";
                $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

                    if($result){

                    }else{
                       die("Database query failed." . mysql_error() . " " . mysqli_connect_error($db));
                    }

        } else { echo "Empty!";
        } 



?>


<form method="post" action="index.php">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>New Sweepstakes</legend>
            <label>Name: </br>
                <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="150" />
            </label> </br>

            <label>Description:</br>
                <textarea name="description" cols="45" rows="10"></textarea>
            </label> </br>

            <label>Adress:</br>
                <input type="text" name="adress" maxlength="1080" />
            </label> </br>  

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: ...and what is the error. Sir!?

Comment: Which problem have you got? Please describe.

Comment: I got: Database query failed.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing `mysql` and `mysqli` functions. Stick with `mysqli`, `mysql` is deprecated (don't use it).

In case you didn't spot it: `mysql_error()` should be `mysqli_error()`

Comment: Thank you. I used the parameter $db. Now i got the error: Database query failed.Failed to read auto-increment value from storage engine

Comment: Well, then that's what you put into Google and try the solutions that come up ;)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to checking what Halcyon writes ( using `mysqli_error()` ), I would also check the query string itself.  Just echo out $query right after it's built  (the `$query = "INSERT..."` line) and when running the script look to see if the output matches what you expect to happen, ie that you see something like `INSERT INTO alfa (name, description, adress) VALUES ('fred', 'blonde dude', 'Anywhere 32B')`.  If anything looks out of place (like maybe you have a ' or " in the inputed data and it's screwing up the string output), fix it and try again.

`echo` and `print` and `print_r()`are your friends when doing detective work on new code to see what is the output expected.

**(edit)**
After reading your update with Halcyon, you should probably check how your auto-incremented field is set up.   If, for example, you've been tinkering with this for a while but only set the auto-increment field  to INT(2), you might have run out of space for numbers (can only go up to 99 with INT(2)).  Increase it to INT(11) or something similar, empty the table, and try again.  You can also try `ALTER TABLE`table_name`AUTO_INCREMENT = 1` to reset the auto numbering.